# How to connect an outlet to an event in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

Hey, I want to connect a button in an alert to an actual button, would I declare the button as UIButton, or something else.  Also, how would I connect the button to the event to the button, because it is in an alert and I can't wire it through interface builder

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView provides the method:

```
- (NSInteger)addButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)title
```

This will return the index of the new button. Button indices start at 0 and increase in the order they are added.

The delegate will then receive a callback:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

When the delegate receives the callback, you can identify which button was pressed and respond accordingly.